# How to loop over list and apply jQuery to change class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning javascript. In following example I am trying to

1. loop over list items to get their original class
2. change it.
   (list item which had class red will change to class green and vice
   versa)

Also I want to keep changing it continuously to get animation effect. How to add javascript and jQuery together?

Do I need to set timeout for each list item?

```
*<style>*
  .red{
        color:red;
    } 
    .green{
        color:green;
    }
*</style>*        




*<body>*
<ul class="list-inline-mb-0 ">
          <li  class="list-inline-item header red">C </li>
          <li class="list-inline-item header green">O</li> 
          <li class="list-inline-item header red">O</li> 
          <li class="list-inline-item header green">L</li> 

</ul>
*</body>*


*<script>*
  $(function()) {

    var myListElem = document.getElementsByClassName('li');

    $('li').each(function() {
    if(myListElem).hasClass("red"){           
     $(myListElem).addClass('green');
         }
    else{
        $(myListElem).addClass('red')
    }

    });  
*</script>*
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add a working snippet (edit and click `[<>]`) - there are many errors that should not be there eg `if(myListElem).hasClass` isn't valid javascript.

Comment: For the animation, use CSS transitions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions.  No need to do any calculations in your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `li` is not a class - `list-inline-item` is.
Second, you are not trying to iterate through an array here `$('li').each(function()...`, since `$('li')` is not how you get an element.
Third, even fixing the loop and adding the repetition (`setInterval()`) won't give you the animation, because you are only adding classes and not removing them. In your example when you check for `red` you only then add `green` and you get `red green` as the resulting class.
Summing up all said things something like this would do:

```js
$(function() {

    var myListElem = document.getElementsByClassName('list-inline-item');
  setInterval(function(){
    for(let i = 0; i < myListElem.length; i++){
    let e = myListElem[i];
      if($(e).hasClass("red")){           
       $(e).addClass('green');
       $(e).removeClass('red');
           }
      else{
          $(e).removeClass('green');
          $(e).addClass('red');
      }
    }
 }, 3000);
  });
```

```css
.red{
        color:red;
    } 
    .green{
        color:green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-inline-mb-0 ">
          <li  class="list-inline-item header red">C </li>
          <li class="list-inline-item header green">O</li> 
          <li class="list-inline-item header red">O</li> 
          <li class="list-inline-item header green">L</li> 

</ul>
```